# How to control the open state of two modals in sequence

Tags: reactjs

In React, I have two modals, Modal1 and Modal2 and I want a button in Modal1 to open Modal2. How do I control the open states of the modals so that I can open and close the modals?

I have a codesandbox showing the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/q86nlljvq4

If you open the first modal and click next, the second modal opens. But if you close it you will never see the second modal again if you try to reopen it.That is, if you press "Open form Dialog" a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control only the modal content instead of having two modals.

```js
function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [modalIndex, setModal] = React.useState(0);

  function handleClickOpen() {
    setModal(0);
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  function handleNext() {
    if (modalIndex < 1) {
      setModal(modalIndex + 1);
    }
  }

  const FirstModal = () => (...)

  const SecondModal = () => (...);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        {!modalIndex ? <FirstModal /> : <SecondModal />}
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleNext} color="primary">
            Next
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/xl63604p7w

Comment: Sorry I think my question may have been unclear. The problem is not with the first modal. I want to destroy it there. The problem is that if I open the second modal and close it, I don't know how to reopen it (because it is mounted with state open === false)

Comment: @herodrigues now it only opens the second modal after closing it the first time. You can never open the first modal once you close the second modal.

Comment: I guess that can be solved with setting the modalIndex to 0 in handleClose though. https://codesandbox.io/s/q86nlljvq4 .Thanks @herodrigues

Comment: A weird sideffect of this is that the first modal is briefly displayed after closing the second modal. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Use `{!modalIndex ? <FirstModal /> : <SecondModal />}` to render the modal content. Do not call `setModal(0)` in `handleClose`. Updated my answer and the sandbox. If its correct, mark it as solved :)